# Pyspark Matrix Transformation

Tags: machine-learning, python, data, preprocessing, pyspark

Let's assume I have the following dataframe in PySpark:

```
Customer    |  product  |   rating
customer1   |  product1 |   0.2343
customer1   |  product2 |   0.4440
customer2   |  product3 |   0.3123
customer3   |  product1 |   0.7430
```

There can be several customer product combinations but every combination is unique already. I want to archive the following outcome in the most efficient manner:

```
Customer (Index) | product 1 | product 2 | product 3
customer 1       |   0.2343  |  0.4440   |  0.0000
customer 2       |   0.0000  |  0.0000   |  0.3123
customer 3       |   0.7430  |  0.0000   |  0.0000
```

Each combination which is not represented in the first table will be set to zero. It has to be efficient because the output matrix will have a size of 59578 rows × 21521 columns and I want to avoid the computational cost as good as possible.

Is there any solutions for this? I didn't found a good solution on the web so far.

Thanks for your help up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this in PySpark is to use `groupBy` and [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot). Since you don't want to do any actual aggregation, just the pivot, you can use `first` here.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

(df.groupBy("Customer")
  .pivot("product")
  .agg(first("rating"))
  .fillna(0))
```

`pivot` will give nulls when there is no value so [`fillna`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) needs to be used as well to give the wanted result.

Comment: sweet and fast. Thank you. For the solution with a huge dataset you mind need to configure the pivotMaxValues as well: spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.pivotMaxValues', u'200000').